# LINQ with groupby and aggregate always shows default value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, model-view-controller, ienumerable

I have 2 model objects, `DriverDetailsSourceObject` which is meant to be for holding the DriverDetailsAPI response and `DriverDetailsView` which is used to show DriverDetails details with aggregated values on the web page.

```cs
public class DriverDetailsSourceObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfPurchase { get; set; }
}

public class DriverDetailsView
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfPurchase { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; } = 1;

    public DriverDetailsView(DriverDetailsSourceObject source)
    {
        Name = source.Name;
        GroupName = source.GroupName;
        DateOfPurchase = source.DateOfPurchase;
    }
}
```

`DriverDetailsView` is used on multiple pages. In 2 of them, `Name`, `GroupName`, `DateOfPurchase` and `Count` is shown where `Count` is always 1 and ToTalCount will be the number of `DriverDetailsView` objects in the collection.

| Name | Count | Group Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RoadAssistance A | 1 | Group A | 1/1/2022 |
| RoadAssistance A | 1 | Group B | 2/1/2022 |
| RoadAssistance A | 1 | Group A | 2/2/2022 |
| RoadAssistance B | 1 | Group A | 2/2/2022 |
| **Total** | 4 |  |  |

In one of the pages, we need to show all the objects grouped by Name and calculate Count and list of GroupNames. I used the following LINQ expression.

```cs
private IEnumerable<DriverDetailsSourceObject> DriverDetails { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<DriverDetailsSourceObject>();
private IEnumerable<DriverDetailsView> DriverDetailsByOption { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<DriverDetailsView>();
.
.
DriverDetails = DriverService.GetDriverOptions(brandName, isAgentLoggedIn);

DriverDetailsByOption = DriverDetails.GroupBy(o => o.Name)
    .Select(d => 
        new DriverDetailsSourceObject()
        { 
            Name = d.First().Name,
            GroupName = d.First().GroupName,
            Count = d.Count()
        })
    .Select(v => new DriverDetailsView(v));
```

I am not getting the correct result using the above LINQ. `Count` is always 1 even after being grouped by `Name`. It could be because the `Count` has a default value 1 in `DriverDetailsView`, which I cannot change as it is used by other pages.

| Name | Count | Group Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RoadAssistance A | 1 | Group A |
| RoadAssistance B | 1 | Group A |
| **Total** | 2 |  |

Expected result is given below:

| Name | Count | Group Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RoadAssistance A | 3 | Group A, Group B |
| RoadAssistance B | 1 | Group A |
| **Total** | 4 |  |

How do I change my LINQ expression to get this result?

Comment: Your `DriverDetailsSourceObject` class doesn't have `Count` property.

Comment: Yes. `DriverDetailsSourceObject` need not have it as it is meant to be for holding the DriverDetailsAPI response only. Api response does not have `Count` property. But we need to show Count in the web page, therefore `Count` property is only added to the view model `DriverDetailsView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue 1:** As you didn't initialize the `Count` in `DriverDetailsView`'s constructor, the `Count` will be 1 by default as initialized.

And meanwhile, you mention that the `DriverDetailsSourceObject` which is your API response class doesn't have the `Count` property.

**Issue 2**:

In your LINQ statement, you return the first `GroupName` instead of multiple `GroupName`:

```cs
GroupName = d.First().GroupName
```

---

**Solution**

**For Issue 1:**
I would suggest using an empty constructor instead of the `DriverDetailsView(DriverDetailsSourceObject source)` constructor.

```cs
public class DriverDetailsView
{
    ...

    public DriverDetailsView() { }
    
    ...
}
```

**For Issue 2:**

To return multiple `GroupName`, you need to select and distinct `GroupName`, next use `String.Join()` to join the `GroupName` array as string.

Change the LINQ statement as below:

```cs
DriverDetailsByOption = DriverDetails.GroupBy(o => o.Name)
    .Select(d => new DriverDetailsView
    { 
        Name = d.Key,
        GroupName = String.Join(",", d.Select(x => x.GroupName).Distinct()),
        Count = d.Count()
    });
```

[Sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lYgmU0)

As you `.GroupBy()` Name, this line

```cs
Name = d.First().Name
```

can be replaced with:

```cs
Name = d.Key
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! worked for me.. Thanks again for the detailed code sample